# How to get configuration value for static value in Quarkus

Tags: java, configuration, quarkus, microprofile

I am rewriting exceptions from an old system and everything was working, but I needed make `BAD_REQUEST` configurable.

```
private static final String BAD_REQUEST = "BDRQ";
```

I tried to just put ConfigProperty, but it doesn't work.

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;

public class SXClientException extends RuntimeException {
  @ConfigProperty(name = "greeting.error", defaultValue = "BDRQ")
  public String BAD_REQUEST;

  private final RuntimeException runtimeException;

  public SXClientException(RuntimeException e) {
    super(e);

    this.runtimeException = e;
  }

  public Status getStatus() {
    if (BAD_REQUEST.equals(runtimeException.getMessage())) {
      return Status.BAD_REQUEST;
    }
    return Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
  }

  // ...
}
```

It probably doesn't work since I make them without any CDI.

```
catch (LegacyOMException e) {
    throw new SXClientException(e);
}
```

I would prefer to avoid creating another bean (and passing the value) just to compare one String. Any idea how can I read a configuration value for a static-ish value?

Comment: Yeah, if you use `@ConfigProperty(...)` inside a class annotated with `@ApplicationScoped` or `@RequestScoped` it DOES work, otherwise it would return null.

Answer (score 7):

you can use org.eclipse.microprofile.config.ConfigProvider.
Works for both static and non static members.

```
public static final String BAD_REQUEST = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("greeting.error",String.class);

public final String BAD_REQUEST = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("greeting.error",String.class);
```

Comment: It works in quarkus `v2.16`

Answer (score 0):

use follow method:

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();  
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/menu.properties");  
properties.load(inputStream );  
System.out.println(properties.getProperty("a"));
```

Comment: I thought about this, but this is worse than passing the value externally. There are so many problems with IO and overrall scalability

Comment: ok, but you want read a config file and not use spring bean, may be not any other ways